# Error occured running SPEC CPU2006 <hmmer> : fatal: writeBlob(0, ...) failed

Tags: arm, benchmarking, gem5

I'm using **arm/gem5.opt, SE mode** to run SPECCPU2006 benchmark hmmer

my commands as follows:

```
~/work_env/FirefoxDownload/gem5-stable/build/ARM/gem5.opt  ~/work_env/FirefoxDownload/gem5-stable/configs/example/se.py \
--cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU \
--caches \
--cacheline=64 \
--l1i_size=16kB \
--l1i_assoc=2 \
--l1d_size=16kB \
--l1d_assoc=2 \
--maxinsts=1000000000 \
--fast-forward=500000000 \
-c /home/sha256/work_env/CPU2006/456.hmmer/exe/hmmer_base.arm \
-o "--fixed 0 --mean 500 --num 500000 --sd 350 --seed 0 /home/sha256/work_env/CPU2006/456.hmmer/data/ref/input/retro.hmm
```

Error seeing like:

```
Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: failed to generate dot output from m5out/config.dot
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000
Switch at instruction count:500000000
info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
info: Increasing stack size by one page.
fatal: writeBlob(0, ...) failed
Memory Usage: 646240 KBytes
```

It seems something wrong with writeBlob, I try to figure out the problem by searching related problem, but it's useless and I'm new to gem5.

And the error doesn't occur in other benchmark

Comment: Simple things first: is your disk full or otherwise failing?  Can you run it under `strace` to see what system call, if any, is failing?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge  Thanks. Find it's ok after switching to a high performance computer